# Facebook AS3 api log in box did work, a day later it does not

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, api, authentication

Yesterday I successfully got my flash project to log in with the facebook as3 api.
Today I tried using the application again, and now its not working. I didn't change any code... Does anyone know how I should approach debugging this or has this happened to anyone else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend created a solution for this issue. I fixed my flash sites and their facebook connect with AS3 SDK.

We're from Mexico so it's in spanish:
[Facebook AS3 Fix](http://ederchrono.com/blog/2012/05/09/arreglando-el-graph-api-de-facebook-para-as3/)

Traduction:

1.- If you're using GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc, delete it.

2.- Download the modified api from [Here](http://ederchrono.com/blog/srcfiles/GRAPHAPI_mod.rar)

3.- Copy the folder in your libraries, if you already had the facebook folder, overwrite.

4.- Compile the project.

The problem happened because facebook modified its http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js file in a way in which the FacebookJSBridge.as file from the as3 api made some calls to "FB.JSON". Now they should be made to "JSON" instead.

Answer (score 1):

1.- If you are using GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc delete it.

2.- Download the modified graph api from [here](http://ederchrono.com/blog/srcfiles/GRAPHAPI_mod.rar)

3.- Paste those folders on your librarys, if you had the facebook folder overwrite it.

4.- Publish your project.

This problem started when facebook changed its file connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js in a way that all the calls made from the as3 file "FacebookJSBridge.as" must be changed from "FB.JSON" to just "JSON".

src: http://ederchrono.com/blog/2012/05/09/fixing-fb-graph-api-for-as3/

Answer (score 0):

The facebook connect functionality on all flash sites made at work have also stopped working. When clicking on the facebook connect button nothing happens. And we’ve made no changes. Now everyone’s working frantically to find a solution.

I hope someone finds a solution soon. Facebook has posted no changes, though they should look into this. I bet tons a flash sites have just stopped working.

Comment: Found the answer to our problem, and there is currently no solution... 
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=418